# Вытащить переменную из функции Javascript

Tags: phonegap, cordova, html, javascript

Не получается вытащить значение переменной из функции, всё время выводится ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: devuuid_raw is not defined

Задача такая: нужно вывести значение переменной за пределы функции, т.к далее значение переменной будет посылаться через другую функцию на сервер.

Код:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("Device is ready");
        var element = document.getElementById('devProps');
        devuuid_raw = device.uuid;
        return devuuid_raw;
        element.innerHTML = 'Идентификатор устройства: ' + device.uuid + '<br />';                                               
    }

    var devuuid = devuuid_raw;
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы абсолютно не понимаете, как работает JavaScript. Рекомендую почитать "Книгу с носорогом". Три грубейшие ошибки:

1. Код после инструкции return (он не выполнится)
2. Объявление переменной без ключевого слова var
3. Непонимание того, что на момент выполнения этой строки:

   var devuuid = devuuid_raw;

onDeviceReady еще не сработал.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, return я изначально не ставил, так посоветовали сделать на другом форме, что для меня тоже показалось странным, переменную без var я объявил глобально, в надежде что она будет видна за пределами функции, но увы она не видна. Насчет "onDeviceReady еще не сработал." не понимаю, а когда он сработает? Нужно ли объявить переменную по-другому?

Comment: он сработает в функции `onDeviceReady()`, вы можете вызвать из нее другую. это называется асинхронное выполнение. для понимания медитируйте на вот такой код:

    var a=0;
    setTimeout(setA,1000); //одноразовое событие таймера, через 1с
    function setA() {
      a=1;
    }
    console.log(a); //0

Comment: Спасибо, это немного проясняет ситуацию. Моя ситуация похожа на ваш пример, но мне как раз нужно чтобы вывелось 1, если исходить из вашего примера

Comment: так

    var a=0;
    setTimeout(setA,1000); //одноразовое событие таймера, через 1с
    function setA() {
      a=1;
      showA();
    }
    function showA() {
       console.log(a); //1
    }

Comment: подобный вариант пробовал, в том то и дело нужно обойтись без второй функции, а сделать  как у вас здесь:

var a=0;
setTimeout(setA,1000); //одноразовое событие таймера, через 1с
function setA() {
  a=1;
}
console.log(a); //0

только чтобы в итоге вывелось 1 т.е чтобы в итоге переменная а была по за функцией и была равна 1 (какое значение ей было задано в функции, такое же должно быть в этой переменной и вне функции)